# SQL query to get the subtotal of some rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, categorical-data

What would be the SQL query script if I want to get the total items and total revenue for each manager including his team? 
Suppose I have this table `items_revenue` with columns:

`|  id  |is_manager|manager_id|   name   |no_of_items| revenue | 
 |   1  |    1     |    0     | Manager1 |    621    |   833   | 
 |   2  |    1     |    0     | Manager2 |    458    |   627   |
 |   3  |    1     |    0     | Manager3 |    872    |   1027  | 
...
 |   8  |    0     |    1     | Member1  |    1258   |   1582  |
 |   9  |    0     |    2     | Member2  |    5340   |   8827  |
 |  10  |    0     |    3     | Member3  |    3259   |   5124  |`

All the managers and their respective members are in the above view table. Member1 is under Manager1, Member2 is under Manager2, and so on, but real data are in random arrangement. I also have a view table with `managers` where I filtered only the managers. I tried getting the totals per team manager with this query: 
`SELECT id, is_manager, manager_id, name, SUM(no_of_items) AS total_items, SUM(revenue) AS total_revenue
FROM items_revenue t
WHERE (SELECT m.id FROM managers m WHERE m.id = t.id)
GROUP BY id HAVING id IN (SELECT m.id FROM managers m);`

However, it only returns the totals of each manager alone, it does not get the totals of their members.

I want my query to output the ff. table:
`|  id  |is_manager|manager_id|   name   |total_items| total_revenue | 
 |   1  |     1    |    0     | Manager1 |   1879    |    2415       | 
 |   2  |     1    |    0     | Manager2 |   5798    |    9454       |
 |   3  |     1    |    0     | Manager3 |   4131    |    6151       |`

Any ideas how to get this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a minor follow up question, then edit my demo with the new data and paste the link here.  Otherwise open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate using a `CASE` expression, which forms a group using the `id` if the `manager_id` be zero, otherwise using the `manager_id`.  The rest of the logic is similar to what you already have.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN manager_id = 0 THEN id ELSE manager_id END AS manager_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN is_manager=1 THEN name END) AS name,
    SUM(no_of_items) AS total_items,
    SUM(revenue) AS total_revenue
FROM items_revenue
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN manager_id = 0 THEN id ELSE manager_id END;
```

[image]

### Demo

One side note: I used a function in the `GROUP BY` clause, which is not ANSI compliant and therefore may not run everywhere.  To fix this, we can first subquery your table to generate the effective manager groups.  Then, use my above answer against this intermediate result.

Comment: Wow! It worked. I have never used CASE WHEN before. Thanks for the quick answer. :)

Comment: When I add columns like, let's say the view table has first_name and last_name columns, I get this error:  
  
`Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'total_items_revenue.first_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @Zhanrah last and first name appear  nowhere in your original question.  If you are changing your data model then you should probably open a new question.  Pasting error messages and data into comments is unlikely to go anywhere.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I just forgot to add the MAX(...) in the SELECT statement. I'm just wondering what's that for? Why is it needed in the GROUP BY CASE WHEN... ?

Comment: It is only possible to select aggregates when using group by.  If you can edit my demo with your new data and paste the link here, I can say more.

Comment: Hi @Tim, I'm just curious, how would you do this with a subquery? The same question above.

Comment: Great question.  You can open a new question to get an answer.