# SQL subquery to get the total

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, categorical-data

Using SQL subquery, how do I get the total items and total revenue for each manager including his team? 
Suppose I have this table items_revenue with columns: 
[image]

All the managers (is_manager=1) and their respective members are in the above table. Member1 is under Manager1, Member2 is under Manager2, and so on, but real data are in random arrangement.

I want my query to output the ff.:

[image]

This is related to [SQL query to get the subtotal of some rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525059/sql-query-to-get-the-subtotal-of-some-rows/47525135?noredirect=1#comment85758618_47525135) but I don't want to use the `CASE` expression. Thanks!

You can copy this to easily create the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items_revenue;
CREATE TABLE items_revenue (id int, is_manager int, manager_id int, name varchar(55), no_of_items int, revenue int);
INSERT INTO items_revenue (id, is_manager, manager_id, name, no_of_items, revenue)
VALUES
    (1  ,    1     ,    0     , 'Manager1' ,    621    ,   833), 
    (2  ,    1     ,    0     , 'Manager2' ,    458    ,   627),
    (3  ,    1     ,    0     , 'Manager3' ,    872    ,   1027 ),
    (8  ,    0     ,    1     , 'Member1'  ,    1258   ,   1582),
    (9  ,    0     ,    2     , 'Member2'  ,    5340   ,   8827),
    (10  ,    0     ,    3     , 'Member3'  ,    3259   ,   5124);
```

Comment: Share the example tables(s)/data as ascii data based table(s) not images.

Comment: is there only one level is or are there multiple levels?

Comment: @RaymondNijland all the managers and their members are just in one table.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use the case expression?

Comment: "all the managers and their members are just in one table." Yes i understand that it's a adjacency list model (parent_id model).. i was wondering if there where more then one level of hierarchical levels?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Nope, just manager and member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `union all` and aggreation:

```
select manager_id, sum(no_of_items) as no_of_items, sum(revenue) as revenue
from ((select ir.manager_id, ir.no_of_items, ir.revenue
       from items_revenue ir
       where ir.is_manager = 0
      ) union all
      (select ir.id, ir.no_of_items, ir.revenue
       from items_revenue ir
       where ir.is_manager = 1
      )
     ) irm
group by manager_id;
```

Note:  This only handles direct reports in the table.  This is the sample data that you provide.  The problem is significantly different if you need all direct reports, so don't modify this question for that situation (ask another).  If that is your need, then MySQL is not the best tool (unless you are using version 8), although you can solve it if you know the maximum depth.

Answer (score 1):

Use two subqueries, one grouped by `id` where `is_manager=1` and another grouped by `manager_id` where `is_manager=0`.

```
SELECT id, name, 
       (t1.total_items + t2.total_items) total_items,
       (t1.total_revenue + t2.total_revenue) total_revenue
FROM (SELECT id, name, 
             sum(no_of_items) total_items, 
             sum(revenue) total_revenue
      FROM   items_revenue
      WHERE  is_manager = 1
      GROUP BY id, name) t1
JOIN (SELECT manager_id,
             sum(no_of_items) total_items, 
             sum(revenue) total_revenue
      FROM   items_revenue
      WHERE  is_manager = 0
      GROUP BY manager_id) t2
ON    t1.id = t2.manager_id;
```

Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/PNNL70529)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  employee.totalit + items_revenue.no_of_items,
  employee.totalerev + items_revenue.revenue,
  employee.manager_id
FROM (SELECT
        sum(no_of_items) AS totalit,
        sum(revenue) as totalerev,
        manager_id
      FROM items_revenue
      WHERE manager_id <> 0
      GROUP BY manager_id) AS employee, items_revenue
WHERE items_revenue.user_id = employee.manager_id;
```